ImportError: cannot import name 'octave' from 'oct2py'
I have issues with the oct2py package ( I think...)
trying to import octave from oct2py.
from oct2py import Oct2Py does work.
I get the error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'octave' from 'oct2py'

trying to do:
from piwavelet.piwavelet import wcoherence, wcross, plotWavelet

I've installed octave through the link: [https://octave.org/download#ms-windows][1]
I've tried from one of the comments from oct2py isn't seeing OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE environment variable (Windows):

Download Octave as a .7z file and unzip it to hard disk
Run post-install.bat (from the folder entitled octave-5.2.0-w64 or something similar)
Restart Windows 10 machine (due to messages encountered during run of post-install.bat)
Run octave-firsttime.vbs
Quit the Octave program
Execute the following python code (in 3.7.6)

and
import os

pathToExecutable = (
    'D:\\wherever\\you\\put\\this\\octave-cli.exe'
)

os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'] = pathToExecutable
from oct2py import octave

I've tried changing the import and path in the _init_ and core files in the oct2py module folder.
But so far none of the options I can find work...
any idea on how to solve this?
Many thanks

Did you perhaps name your own script oct2py.py?  That would be found by the import, before the actual module.

No, I don't have a script called oct2py.py. I've been working in the console of spyder.
